# Imported CSV nodes need to be combined

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I imported a CSV file into neo4j but then later discovered that there are two nodes for the same person due to a space at the end of the name in part of the csv file.

How can I remove that space and combine those two nodes? I can't seem to figure out if this is a node label or something else.

Table view:

```
{
  "batch_author": "Chance Will"
}

{
  "batch_author": "Chance Will "
}
```

I need to combine these two nodes and make them as one single node.

Comment: The neo4j browser's "table view" just shows node properties, not labels. Do the nodes in question have labels, is `batch_author ` the only property you care about, and does each "bad" node always have a corresponding "good" node? Also, do any of these nodes have relationships?

Answer (score 0):

The "table view" is just showing the node properties.

This query uses the APOC procedure [apoc.refactor.mergeNodes](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/) to merge the 2 nodes (and their relationships -- see the docs):

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.batch_author ENDS WITH ' '
MATCH (m) WHERE m.batch_author = TRIM(n.batch_author)
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([m, n], {properties: 'discard', mergeRels: true}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```